# Unexpected token ILLEGAL error when lines of code are split

Tags: javascript

I was just playing around with the source code of **[timesheet.js](https://github.com/sbstjn/timesheet.js/blob/master/source/javascripts/timesheet.js#L35)**(see the specific line) and came across a small bug, see the below line of code:

```
            '<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
            + bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
```

When i generate the HTML and split it in 2 lines everything works fine, But if i do the following I.E. split the HTML in 3 lines , like so:

```
            '<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
            + bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " 
            class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
```

I get the following Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Why ? Why is it when i spit the code into multiple lines does the error occur ? can anybody explain this ? that would be my only question.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Because the browsers are tolerant enough to accept the line break as an end of code line. In your case the declared string is not properply closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, duh, you split the code in the middle of a string literal. You can't just split anywhere you want - there's rules to the language. It's as if you split it in the middle of `getStartOffset` to get `getS` on one line, and `tartOffset` on another - it's just plain wrong.

The original split was in an expression - note how the second line starts with `+`, and *isn't* in a string literal.

A correct split would be something like this:

```
'<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
+ bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " class="bubble bubble-' 
+ (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
```

If you need to split in the middle of a string literal, you need to end it and append another:

```
'<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
+ bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " '
+ 'class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
```

Comment: Thanks , your name means something really bad in an indian language LOL . Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

By default, the javascript engines don't allow a cariage return in a string literal. So, if you add a cariage return like in you 2nd exmple, the engine comme to the end of the line but can't find the end of string char.

You can easily fix your exemple like this :

```
'<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
+ bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " '
+ 'class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
```